# IE 8 jQuery click event - $(this) resulting in undefined

Tags: jquery, html, internet-explorer-8

Having a spot of bother with having a link container with a table inside. Initially I had a  tag surrounding the div(with table inside) as it is "allowed" in HTML5 but when in IE 6-8 clicking on the table didn't redirect the page.

Looking at some similar posts here I found the problem was nesting block elements inside in-line elements where IE was (to my amazement) doing the correct implementation. To solve this I added a wrapping div, gave it a data-path attribute of the URL and set up a click event in jQuery.

The problem is now the click event works but returns undefined. if you click on the table contents. I am guessing it is something to do with my use of $(this) but not 100%.

The HTML:

```
<div class="single-event" data-path="someUrl">
   <div class="">
      <h1></h1>
      <p></p>
      <table>
          ........
      </table>
   </div>
</div>
```

The Js

```
$('.single-event').click(function () {
     window.location.href = $(this).attr('data-path');
});
```

Please let me know if I can improve my question and thank you for any responses!

Comment: is $(this) returns undefined or just `$`. If its the latter than you're missing jquery framework

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue might be that the document dom is not ready when the click handler is being assigned.

Wrap the assignment function in a document ready event handler, like so.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
         $('.single-event').click(function () {
             window.location.href = $(this).attr('data-path');
         });
    });
</script>
```